# How to create a search bar using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a search bar using HTML and JavaScript, but I'm not  understanding why my code isn't working.

```js
document.querySelector("#search-form").onsubmit = function() {
  // Grab whatever the user typed in
  console.log("It worked");
  let searchTermInput = document.querySelector("#search-id").value.trim();
  let end = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=473716561aeaecdcec4a3a598dae6440&language=en-US&query=" + searchTermInput + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
  ajax(end);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="" class="col-12" id="search-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-12 mt-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="search-id" class="sr-only">Search:</label>
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="search-id" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-4 col-sm-auto">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .form-row -->
</form>
```

Comment: What’s happening that you aren’t expecting?

Comment: So I'm working with the movie database api, when ever the user inputs a word associated with a movie into the search bar the page will display movies related to the word they search. My problem is is that when ever I input and search something nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit button is performing its default function which is submitting the form. Stop the submitting using `preventDefault` and it will work. After everything is done submit the form

```js
document.querySelector("#search-form").onsubmit = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  // Grab whatever the user typed in
  console.log("It worked");
  let searchTermInput = document.querySelector("#search-id").value.trim();
  let end = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=473716561aeaecdcec4a3a598dae6440&language=en-US&query=" + searchTermInput + "&page=1&include_adult=false";
  ajax(end);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="" class="col-12" id="search-form">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-12 mt-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <label for="search-id" class="sr-only">Search:</label>
      <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="search-id" placeholder="Search...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mt-4 col-sm-auto">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .form-row -->
</form>
```